# Will this help become more fit?

Tags: gym, bicycling

140ib 18 year old girl. My diet is generally good but I've never really dedicated my time to fitness. I want to get the yearly pass for the gym at my school so I can start regularly exercising.

I'm currently thinking of doing indoor cycling for about an hour 3-5 days a week with maybe a couple of other exercises. Is this enough to help me become more fit?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "fit"?  What objective measures would you use?

Comment: As for me, I trying to walk from home to my work office and back by my feet only (in sum it's like 12km). Really helped me to lose some fat. Not as exausting as cycling or jogging

Answer (score 4):

The gym that I train at has several rather cheesy quotes sprayed on the walls, one of the ones that seems particularly apt here is "You don't have to be great to start, but you have to start to be great".

What I mean by that is that if you haven't dedicated any time to fitness in the past, then any time you can dedicate to fitness, be it cycling for an hour, or something else, is going to be an improvement and help you become more fit.

I would suggest adding in some basic strength work, so something like squats, lunges, inverted rows, that sort of thing, as the benefits of getting stronger are numerous and can help with other activities, such as cycling.

Comment: I second this. As for the strength workouts, it can even be just bodyweight exercises at the start.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be committed to this. Nice work! That's the first part of the battle won.

Indoor cycling is great! Even 3 times a week is enough. When you get tired through the session, don't stop. Keep going, especially when you think you can't, because that's when you start to become fit. Every second you keep going you get exponentially fitter than you were a second before. It might seem hard, even impossible, but believe me, it's worth it. Afterwards you will experience a rush like you wouldn't believe. Pretty soon you'll find yourself going 4-5 times a week, maybe even outdoors, the sky is the limit.

So yeah I just wanna encourage you because I can relate to where you are now. Just push through for 2, maybe 3 weeks, and the fitness bug will bite, and you will be well on your way to an endorphin-filled, wide awake life. Good luck!